# Outlook app constantly requiring two-factor authentication (TFA)

Tags: 9.0-pie, outlook, 2fa

I have my Outlook app synced to a number of different accounts, including Gmail, Blacknight, and 3 different Outlook 365 email accounts.

For the last 36 - 48 hours, 2 of the Outlook email accounts have been constantly requesting me to sign back into the account, using TFA. This seems to happen every 2 hours or so.

I've tried going into the settings, and resetting the accounts, but this does not seem to work.

From memory, the settings on the email accounts are set to require TFA every 14 days.

This issue does not happen for the other accounts linked to the Outlook app.

- Outlook version is 4.0.16, last updated on the 19th Sept 2019.
- Android version is 9, with patch security from 1st August, 2019.
- Phone is a Samsung Note 8.

Any suggestions on how to resolve, as it is very annoying?